# Возможно ли изменить иконку Snapengage-чата для мобильных устройств?

Tags: javascript, html

В настройках чата внутри crm **snapengage** можно изменить вид кнопки, единая кнопка под все экраны, возможно ли изменить её для мобильных девайсов?

*заменить саму иконку. изначально она загружается в  crm.

Comment: То есть вам нужно на разных девайсов разная кнопка?

Comment: Да, верно.  Но в настройках оба девайса подсасывают только один вид иконки: https://prnt.sc/hkv9si

Answer (score 1):

```js
if($(window).width() <= 600) {
 $("#img").attr("src","https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/69/69075.svg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/281/281769.svg" id="img" width="50px">
```

Comment: Спасибо, но немного не то нужно, мой косяк.

Comment: @shtativ, я уже исправил